# NSString truncated automatically

Tags: objective-c, string, truncate

I have a rest webservice which provides a picture file, base64 encoded, in a xml. 
My App consumes this webservice. Up to this point everything works fine.

`<News>
  <PictureContent>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAjsA[AND A LOT MORE...]</PictureContent>
</News>`

My problem is that this that this PictureContent-String is truncated during the runtime of my app and I have no clue why.

I already tried (gdb)po(NSString *)myString and that command in the debugger console returns also just a truncated string.

During the runtime the string looks like "*** TRUNCATED ***jdklasjdKASDJALKSJDSALDJ[AND A LOT MORE"

Comment: WHy use `NSString` instead of `NSData` for data? Please show the code that creates the `NSString` of `PictureContent`.

Comment: I have no clue why either, and I never will unless you post your code.

Comment: iam using a middleware solution which generates classes for me to handle the webservice call. therefore iam determined regarding the datatype.

i also figured out that after 285 characters the described behavior appears (truncating the string...).

Comment: Retagged. Not specific to either Xcode or iPhone.